# Reset node counter on neo4j-shell's dump

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm running two different Neo4j servers and running the same queries on them in the same order.

I want to check if both databases are equivalent, for that purpose I'm generating a dump of the entire database (and I do realize this is not a real alternative for huge databases) with `bin/neo4j-shell -c "dump" > /home/my_user/dump.txt` and them comparing the md5 hashes generated with `md5sum dump.txt`.

The generated `dump.txt` files look pretty much identical except that the variables which identify the nodes are sometimes different, which of course generates completely different hashes for each file. Example:

dump.txt #1

```
begin
commit
begin
create (_6:`Person` {`name`:"Arthur", `title`:"King"})
create (_7:`Person` {`name`:"Saladin", `title`:"Sultan"})
create (_8:`Army` {`name`:"Saxon army"})
create (_6)-[:`FIGHTS_AGAINST`]->(_8)
create (_7)-[:`LEADS`]->(_8)
;
commit
```

dump.txt #2

```
begin
commit
begin
create (_7:`Person` {`name`:"Arthur", `title`:"King"})
create (_8:`Person` {`name`:"Saladin", `title`:"Sultan"})
create (_9:`Army` {`name`:"Saxon army"})
create (_7)-[:`FIGHTS_AGAINST`]->(_9)
create (_8)-[:`LEADS`]->(_9)
;
commit
```

I'm guessing right now it works based on the number of nodes the database has had so far and when I clean it with `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n` it doesn't reset this counter. The only way I found to reset it is by restarting the server, which isn't exactly practical.

I guess the simplest way to solve my issue would be to make a script that erases all numbers preceded by an _, but wouldn't it, in very specific situations, generate false positives? Like if the queries where very similar and in the same order but updated different nodes.

Does anyone have a better alternative? Maybe a command to reset this node counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using regular expressions on Bash to achieve the desired result of removing all node identifiers from the files.

`cat dump.txt | sed s/\(_[0-9]*/\(/g > dump_new.txt`

Which from a `dump.txt` like this one:

```
begin
commit
begin
create (_18:`Person` {`name`:"Arthur", `title`:"King"})
create (_19:`Person` {`name`:"Saladin", `title`:"Sultan"})
create (_20:`Army` {`name`:"Saxon army"})
create (_18)-[:`FIGHTS_AGAINST`]->(_20)
create (_19)-[:`LEADS`]->(_20)
;
commit
```

Generates a `dump_new.txt` like this one:

```
begin
commit
begin
create (:`Person` {`name`:"Arthur", `title`:"King"})
create (:`Person` {`name`:"Saladin", `title`:"Sultan"})
create (:`Army` {`name`:"Saxon army"})
create ()-[:`FIGHTS_AGAINST`]->()
create ()-[:`LEADS`]->()
;
commit
```